# Displaying two rows of data in one line in a Crystal Report report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a simple report where each data row consist of two fields ( Field1, Field2) to save paper I would like to print two rows per line in the report:

Field1 Field2  {bigger space} Field1 Field2

Is this doable in CR?

Thank,
Ignacio

Comment: can you explain with a screenshot?

Comment: what if you use 2 subreports and place them side by side. You will have to add some conditions though.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting your details section to contain multiple columns of data.

In the Section Expert, select the Details section of the report and then check "Format with Multiple Columns". This will enable a fourth tab on the same screen called "Layout" where you can tell CR how to format each of these columns and how to print records across the page.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, Your 2 years old answer save my day.

Answer (score 0):

you can use subreports to do so, on your main report add two subreports the first one to display field1 and the other to display field2.